# Executar arquivo ao invés de redirecionar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte javascript:

```
$(".enviar_email").click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    window.location.href = "<? echo base_url('boleto/email/'); ?>/" + cliente + "/" + datainicial + "/" + datafinal;    
});
```

Preciso que ao clicar, não redirecione, apenas execute a url. Sem redirecionar, como faço?

Comment: A URL retorna algum dado?

Comment: Não, porque eu faço uma execução nela em background apenas...

Comment: Ajax não seria o caminho?

Answer (score 2):

Achei uma solução, deixo registrado para quem servir!

```
$(".enviar_email").on("click", function(evt) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<? echo base_url('boleto/email/'); ?>/" + cliente + "/" + datainicial + "/" + datafinal,
        data: {id: 1 },
        type: 'BOLETO'
    }).done(function() {
         $('#myModal').modal('hide');
         $('#myModalBoletoOK').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Neste caso, executa a URL e mostra a mensagem de "Boleto enviado" (no meu caso)